Excel VBA - Table removed by copy/paste values or range.value = range.value
I'm trying to copy over a whole sheet of inputs to a spreadsheet.  The problem comes because on the target sheet there are a number of tables, which I need to remain tables.
When I copy / paste special values over the whole area then the tables are removed, just leaving the (new) values and (old) format but no table functionality.
I have tried to used Range.Value = Range.Value2, but that also removes the tables.
I can copy over the table data for each table in turn, but things would be a lot simpler if I could just bring the whole sheet over at once.

Maybe you should do that differently. Copy to a new sheet, copy over the tables from target sheet and then copy it to over target.

Please show us your code and a screenshot of what your are copying and the target sheet.

Have got around this by doing it cell by cell, but it would be good to understand why tables are removed when pasted over with just values.

The code that copied over the values is:
Range(wks_Target.Cells(1, 1), wks_Target.Cells(int_Rows, int_Cols)).Value = Range(wks_Data.Cells(1, 1), wks_Data.Cells(int_Rows, int_Cols)).Value2
The inputs are coming from a sheet with just values on - not tables etc.
It's just a worksheet with some named ranges and some tables that is being copied over to.

This is probably the dumbest thing you'll read all day, but if you're that interested in having exactly the same information in your destination sheet, then why don't you simply rename the sheet? :-)

@Sicrates: Don't put code as comment. Edit your question and put it there (don't forget to format it as code).

Can confirm (but not explain) the behavior:
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1)
    .DataBodyRange = .DataBodyRange
End With

will clear the whole table.
However, there is an easy workaround: Use the Value property:
    .DataBodyRange.Value = .DataBodyRange.Value


Thanks- I was looking to just copy over the whole worksheet of values, but that gets rid of the tables.  The approach above would require me to bring over the values table by table rather then just dumping the whole sheet of inputs in one go.
